# PHP Function to Indent PHP Code?

Tags: php, formatting

I'm looking for a PHP function that will take a string like this:

```
    function func() {
           $testing;
       $testing;
}
```

And turn it into something like this:

```
function func() {
    $testing;
    $testing;
}
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is your friend:

http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier

Comment: That looks good - do you know of anything a little more lightweight?

Comment: yep, something that looks like a single function would be appreciated.